# How to use attribute to read another collection in mongodb?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack

In my MEAN stack app, I am able to display an `Event` object from my mongoDb.

Below is an example of what that object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d415feedb87bc4470c560be"),
    "event_name" : "test event",
    "event_venue" : "5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb",
    "event_artist" : "5d406855171c152868ba71c8",
    "event_price" : "10",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here is the Typescript that retrieves the above data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    getEvent(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.eventService.getEvent(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                this.event = res;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the `getEvent()` method in my EventService:

```
getEvent(id) {
    return this
        .http
          .get(`${this.uri}/get/${id}`);
}
```

Below is the current HTML:

```
<div>
    Event Name: {{event.event_name}}
    Venue: {{event.event_venue}}
    Artist:{{event.event_artist}}
    Price: {{event.event_price}}
</div>
```

The above values `event_venue` & `event_artist` are ID's of `venue` & `artist` objects.

For example, here is my `venue` object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb"),
    "venue_name" : "diceys",
    "venue_location" : "camden street",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The *_id* of `venue` is *event_venue* in `event`.

Rather than just display `event.event_venue`, can someone please tell me how I can use it to retrieve `venue.venue_name`?

Comment: Is this same as your other question? $lookup thing??

Comment: Hi @srinivasy No, it's different. Rather than just display `event.event_venue`, I want to use it to display `venue.venue_name`. As it is the value is a PK in `Venue` & a FK in `Event`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing something in your frontend you should change your query inside mongodb with aggregation and get complete detail.

Eg:

```
db.event.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'venue',
            localField: 'event_venue',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'venue'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$venue"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: true,
            event_name: true,
            event_venue: "$venue.venue_name",
            event_artist: true,
            event_price: true

        }
    }
])
```

Note:

1. `event_venue` and `event_artist` must of type `ObjectId` not string to match properly.
2. I am not doing look on `artist` because you did not provided its details if you want you can modify add the below code to get proper artist details also same as venue.

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'artist',
        localField: 'event_artist',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'artist'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$artist"
},
{
    event_artist:"$artist.name",
}
```

Response

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d415feedb87bc4470c560be"),
    "event_name" : "test event",
    "event_artist" : ObjectId("5d406855171c152868ba71c8"),
    "event_price" : "10",
    "event_venue" : "diceys"
}
```

#### Angular

```
<div>
    Event Name: {{event.event_name}}
    Venue: {{event.event_venue}}
    Artist:{{event.event_artist}}
    Price: {{event.event_price}}
</div>
```

Comment: How do I call this query from the frontend?

Comment: I haven't written a mongodb query in my app yet, & don't know where to put them in terms of the typescript, etc.

Comment: You are calling  this API, `http.get(`${this.uri}/get/${id}`);`
which is written on nodejs server by calling this api you are getting the result i hope. you need to replace the query at backend. 
As you mentioned its a MEAN stack application. so this is a portion of `N` nodejs.

Comment: if you want to do it @frontend then you need to call three api which can give you
records for event,  artist and venue
then just get what you want by processing all three record.